# What is wrong with my tags summaries?

Tags: support, tags

A couple weeks ago I spent some time to add wiki tags summaries for many void tags. Some of them were accepted (thank you), but some are rejected.

Please explain what I did wrong, so I could not make the same errors again.

These tags are eg. [jews](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jews) (https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/9068/revisions), [everyday-life](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everyday-life) (https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/9053/revisions), [tanks](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanks) (https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/9088/revisions).

Comment: I've rejected your latest one (not linked here), because it was more or less a copy from Wikipedia. Please don't do that, the tag wiki should ideally provide guidance on using the tag, and not so much an encyclopedic / dictionary definition of the tag. Also, _always_ take care to properly attribute content you re-use.

Comment: The last two were approved by everybody. *confused*

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/ if you haven't already.

Comment: @YannisRizos I always strictly respect copyright and usually do not copy Wikipedia, although it is open source. I don't know what you mean "the latest one", but probably I wanted to put a definition and then to extend it. It is sometimes difficult to develop something new, if I am not an expert, but for me it is important to have some information even if not much. Use of tags should be clear and I made a trial expecting that someone will improve it rather than reject (my opinion is the same as T.E.D.'s answer). I think it should be left some comment for me what is wrong --

Comment: -- I'm sure not everything in [tag:tanks] was wrong. I see only "revised" and nothing more. (sorry for long comment)

Comment: This is the edit I rejected: http://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5287

Comment: I agree, the first sentence was copied from Wikipedia

Comment: @YannisRizos Could you please explain me how could I get to such a page? As I have not enough reputation, I can't reach it by Review->Suggested edits, and I have no information what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You (and everyone else, regardless of reputation) can find all your edit suggestions in the [activity tab in your profile](http://history.stackexchange.com/users/2395/voitcus?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) (sorted for "suggestions"). Similarly, all my reviews can be found in the [same tab on my profile](http://history.stackexchange.com/users/739/yannis-rizos?tab=activity&sort=reviews) (sorted for "reviews").

Comment: Thank you @YannisRizos, if I'd known this before, I would have not asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm very glad that you asked this - I reviewed your tag summaries and approved about half of them.  I wanted to leave feedback for the ones I rejected, but I didn't know how to do so, and then I got distracted by tasks for which people pay me.

If there was a pattern to the rejections it was because I felt there was a dangerous ambiguity in the text.  Unfortunately enough time has gone by that I don't remember the details, but I remember looking at one of the texts and thinking, "I can see what he *meant* to say, but I'm not sure that it says that."  I remember thinking that it was the kind of sentence that I could see myself writing, and then being pilloried for not spotting the ambiguity.  I really wished I could have offered an constructive suggestion or edit rather than a rejection. As I said, I meant to go back and try to fix that, but got distracted by a shiny paycheck.

Tags are constrained to be very brief, and sometimes that brevity seems to facilitate misunderstanding.  When the subject is contentious, any misunderstanding can lead to the kind of fractious debate that undermines SE.  I wish I could remember the details, but I do recall rejecting your first attempt at a summary tag for Jews, and then approving the second because it was much clearer.

In any case I'm glad you asked for the feedback - the site doesn't offer the chance to offer feedback on tag wiki content. In every case I appreciated that you'd drafted the tag, and liked most of what I saw. I only rejected when I saw something that was unintentionally substantively misleading, or that might generate unpleasant arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It could just be a matter of who happened to come across your tag wiki edits.

I have about the most permissive attitude toward tag wiki edits you are liable to find (IMHO just about any wiki is better than no wiki). So if the old wiki was blank and you luck out and get me to look at it first, you are quite likely to get your edits accepted.

OTOH, you could have bad luck and get a moderator with some standards. :-)

Comment: Thanks for nice words, but this is in fact no answer to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/9068/revisions has classic "Who is a Jew?" problems.

https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/9053/revisions is grossly out of line with the technical meaning of "everyday life" in historiography.  Its a bowdlerisation at best.

I think I skipped one of the tank ones when I checked, might have rejected.  It involved (IIRC) controversial assumptions about tracks, turrets.